# Set environment variable securely for PowerShell session

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

Is there a way to set environment variable securely for a PowerShell session?

```
$env:mypwd = "don't display this as i set it"
```

Or can I use a local file to place my passwords in and retrieve in script?

Comment: If this is meant for passwords then don't use an env var, export your encrypted SecureString with DPAPI so its secure and can be only used by your user and from the computer it was exported. [`Export-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7.3#example-3-encrypt-an-exported-credential-object-on-windows) is a very good way of exporting a PSCredential in a secure way (on Windows only!).

Answer (score 0):

*This works on Windows PowerShell 5.1 and also PowerShell on **Windows** (tested using PowerShell 7.3.2). This will not work on PowerShell for Linux/OSX as the underlying implementation uses the Data Protection API (DPAPI).*

As @SantiagoSquarzon suggests in the comments, you can encrypt a plaintext string (using [ProtectedData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)) for file storage and retrieval such that it cannot be converted back into plaintext from just the file alone if someone tried from another account or using a different machine.

At the point that you need to set the password, do something like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Security") | Out-Null

$Plaintext = Read-Host  # User enters "Top Secret"

$Scope = [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Plaintext)
$Protected = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($Bytes, $null, $Scope)

$Protected | Export-Clixml password.xml
```

This produces the file `password.xml` which contains the encrypted version and it is tied to the current user only. You can specify a scope of [`LocalMachine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope) if you really want but I've never found that a useful option myself.

When your script needs to access the secret then use something like the following:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Security") | Out-Null

$Scope = [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser

$Protected = Import-Clixml password.xml

$Bytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($Protected, $null, $Scope)
$Plaintext = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($Bytes)

$Plaintext  # -> "Top Secret"
```

Comment: `Read-Host -AsSecureString | Export-Clixml securedpwd.xml` would work just fine.